# Generate appropriate pattern for IntlDateFormatter()->format() based on locale in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, internationalization

I'm trying to rely on IntlDateFormatter to **return the current date in a locale-based format**. This means DD/MM/YYYY for it_IT, de_DE, fr_FR... or MM/DD/YYYY for en_US and so on for all the possible locales.

I'm trying to follow the same solution I used to retrieve the current month's name:

```
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter("it_IT", IntlDateFormatter::FULL, IntlDateFormatter::FULL);
$formatter->setPattern("MMMM");
return $formatter->format($this);
```

This code correctly returns "January", "gennaio" etc.

The problem is, I cannot figure out the right pattern to get the date in the current locale format. The [ICU User Guide](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime) mentions the **DateTimePatternGenerator class**, and this looks like it! But I cannot find it in PHP.

I would like to avoid a custom, huge switch-case and rely on built-in function instead.

**It must be pure PHP.**

Any help?

Comment: are you open to use some JS code?

Comment: I added "It must be pure PHP", thanks.

Comment: I had quite a similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35129924/how-to-format-date-with-a-intldateformatter-using-medium-or-full-datetype-but-w/35149860 and have found out that currently only HHVM supports that. All we can do is wait.

Comment: See https://blog.ksimka.io/a-long-journey-to-formatting-a-date-without-a-year-internationally-with-php/ why it's impossible by now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you want to get pattern from ICU itself, or just format your DateTime. Here you have both solutions.

**Basics:**

You're doing well with you actual code for retrieving month name. IntlDateFormatter is pretty customizable, and it all depend on options you gave it.

**Getting date with year, month and day depending on locale:**

```
$locale = "en_GB";
$dateType = IntlDateFormatter::SHORT;//type of date formatting
$timeType = IntlDateFormatter::NONE;//type of time formatting setting to none, will give you date itself
$formatter =new IntlDateFormatter($locale, $dateType, $timeType);
$dateTime = new DateTime("2015-02-28");
echo $formatter->format($dateTime);
```

will give you

> 28/02/2015

You can play with other options of IntlDateFormatter. There's SHORT, MEDIUM, LONG, FULL and NONE - you can read about them and check example ouput [here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php#intl.intldateformatter-constants).

**[Getting pattern](http://php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.getpattern.php) from formatter**

```
$formatter->->getPattern();
```

will give you something like

> dd/MM/yyyy

I hope this will help you. I've been struggling with it for a long time to do it properly :)