# How to format date with a IntlDateFormatter using MEDIUM or FULL datetype, but without a year?

Tags: php, date, localization, internationalization

> First of all: I know that I can manually create a bunch of config files with corresponding patterns for every locale; actually I try to find a workaround with using only IntlDateFormatter.

I'll try to explain with examples.

```
<?php

$tz = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Moscow');
$now = time();
foreach (['en_US', 'ja_JA', 'ru_RU'] as $locale) {
    printf("%s:\n", $locale);

    foreach ([IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM, IntlDateFormatter::LONG] as $datetype) {
        $formatter = new IntlDateFormatter($locale, $datetype, IntlDateFormatter::NONE);
        printf("- %s\n", $formatter->format($now));
    }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/iJOT4

This produces

```
en_US:
- Feb 1, 2016
- February 1, 2016
ja_JA:
- 2016/02/01
- 2016年2月1日
ru_RU:
- 1 февр. 2016 г.
- 1 февраля 2016 г.
```

And I need

```
en_US:
- Feb 1
- February 1
ja_JA:
- 02/01
- 2月1日
ru_RU:
- 1 февр.
- 1 февраля
```

The first idea was to extract a pattern for given locale and remove any 'y' and 'Y' letters. But as you can see, there is more than just a 4-digit year: all that commas, slashes, labels (like 'г.' and '年').

PS:

Actually, what I want from an ideal `IntlDateFormatter` implementation is a smart pattern, where all components are in their places, but I can configure what pattern to use for each component. Like: instead of `'d MMMM y г.'` pattern for `ru_RU` formatter has a `'dmy'` pattern, and for `d` component it has `d` pattern, `m` - `MMMM` and `y` - `y г.`. So I could say `y` component is a '' (empty string), and voila.

Also, if you are aware of any library that already does this — please, let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, currently it's impossible. I've found that `intl` PHP extension simply lacks of `DateTimePatternGenerator` (http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime), which is exactly what I need.

> The DateTimePatternGenerator class provides a way to map a request for a set of date/time fields, along with their width, to a locale-appropriate format pattern. The request is in the form of a “skeleton” which just contains pattern letters for the desired fields using the representation for the desired width. In a skeleton, anything other than a pattern letter is ignored, field order is insignificant, and there are two special additional pattern letters that may be used: 'j' requests the preferred hour-cycle type for the locale (it gets mapped to one of 'H', 'h', 'k', or 'K'); 'J' is similar but requests no AM/PM marker even if the locale’s preferred hour-cycle type is 'h' or 'K'.
>
> For example, a skeleton of “MMMMdjmm” might result in the following format patterns for different locales:
>
> ```
> locale | format pattern for skeleton “MMMMdjmm” | example
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> en_US    "MMMM d  'at'  h:mm a"                   April 2 at 5:00 PM
> es_ES    "d 'de' MMMM, H:mm"                      2 de abril, 17:00
> ja_JP    "M月d日 H:mm"                              4月2日 17:00
> ```

Also, I've found that HHVM has implemented it — https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/commit/bc84daf7816e4cd268da59d535dcadfc6cf01085 . I hope one day this will be ported to PHP.

**UPD:** I've written a huge post on the problem — https://blog.ksimka.com/a-long-journey-to-formatting-a-date-without-a-year-internationally-with-php/

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit ugly, but we can do something like this if you are OK defining the pattern for a limited number of locales and set a sensible default for the other locales.

```php
$formatter = match ($lang) {
    'en' => new \IntlDateFormatter($lang, pattern: "MMMM d  'at'  h:mm a"),
    'es' => new \IntlDateFormatter($lang, pattern: "d 'de' MMMM, H:mm"),
    'ja' => new \IntlDateFormatter($lang, pattern: "M月d日 H:mm"),
    default => new \IntlDateFormatter($lang, \IntlDateFormatter::LONG, \IntlDateFormatter::NONE),
};

$date = $formatter->format($datetime);
```